# Running code when a variable is accessed in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class Person. It must throw a SittingError if its running_speed variable is accessed while Person.sitting == True.

```
class SittingError(Exception):
    pass

class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sitting = False
        self.running_speed = 4

bob = Person()
print(bob.running_speed) # Works fine, he's not sitting
bob.sitting = True
print(bob.running_speed) # Throws SittingError, as running_speed was accessed while sitting
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You could use a `@property` decorator and throw an exception in the getter if `sitting == true`.

Comment: Make `sitting` and `running_speed` private fields with `getter`s and `setter`s. That way you can tell if the field has been accessed.

Comment: @property is exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `@property` decorator and throw an exception in the getter if `sitting == true`.

```
class SittingError(Exception):
    pass

class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sitting = False
        self._running_speed = 4

    @property
    def running_speed(self):
        if self.sitting:
            raise SittingError()
        return self._running_speed

    @running_speed.setter
    def running_speed(self, speed):
        self._running_speed = speed

bob = Person()
print(bob.running_speed) # Works fine, he's not sitting
bob.sitting = True
print(bob.running_speed)
```